# Can't find mysql-admin package in 12.04 repositories

Tags: repository

I've installed the Precise Pangolin today. Just can't find some packages like `mysql-admin` and `libcv-dev`... Is there something special about LTS repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is that it has been marked as an End Of Life product and removed from the repositories, they recommend using MySQL Workbench:

> December 18, 2009 [EOL of MySQL Query Browser, MySQL Administrator,
>   MySQL Migration Toolkit](http://dev.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html)
>
> With the beta releases of MySQL Workbench 5.2 well under way, we are
>   announcing the EOL of the MySQL GUI Tools Bundle.
>
> The MySQL Tools team has been working on MySQL Workbench 5.2 to give
>   DBAs and developers an integrated tools environment for:
>
> ```
> Database Design & Modeling
> SQL Development (replacing MySQL Query Browser)
> Database Administration (replacing MySQL Administrator)
> ```
>
> MySQL Workbench 5.2 also provides:
>
> ```
> Remote Administration (using SSH-Tunneling)
> Python scripting and plugins
> Native GUI for Windows, Mac, Linux
> ```
>
> A future release of MySQL Workbench (post 5.2) will add a migration
>   plugin, providing features comparable to the MySQL Migration Toolkit
>   component of the MySQL GUI Tools Bundle. The MySQL Support team will
>   continue to provide technical assistance for MySQL Migration Toolkit
>   until such migration support functionality is released in MySQL
>   Workbench, but no new development or bug fixes will be provided
>   against the existing MySQL Migration Toolkit product.
>
> MySQL Support will continue to answer questions and provide assistance
>   related to MySQL GUI Tools Bundle, as well as assist our customers in
>   upgrading from those tools to MySQL Workbench 5.2 until June 30, 2010.
>
> Starting Dec 18, 2009, MySQL will no longer accept bug reports
>   submitted against the MySQL GUI Tools Bundle, and existing bug reports
>   against these tools will no longer be worked on. Users should instead
>   download, use, and submit bug reports (where necessary) against MySQL
>   Workbench. Downloads of the MySQL GUI Tools Bundle will remain
>   available, but will be moved into the MySQL Archives location.
>
> Users should begin planning to upgrade to MySQL Workbench 5.2 GA.

Too bad, I really liked mysql-admin ;(